# Scope of variables defined inside parallel_for

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, parallel.for

To execute a loop in parallel I am using:

```
int testValues[16]={5,2,2,10,4,4,2,100,5,2,4,3,29,4,1,52};
parallel_for (1, 100, 1, [&](int i){ 
    int var1;
    for (var1=1; var1<=20000; var1++) {
        int var2, var3, var4;
        double u[45],pl;
        int values[16]={-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
        /* ... */
        for (var4=0; var4<16; var4++) {
            if (values[var4] != testValues[var4]) break;
        }
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

Can I be sure that all variables defined inside the `parallel_for` block (i.e. `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4`, `u`, `pl`, `values`) will have scope local to each loop iteration, i.e. will not be shared across threads or loop iterations?

Also, is it safe for multiple threads to access `testValues` like this as long as they are only reading (not writing to it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All variables inside the lambda are local to the thread which executes it, so yes they are safe.

Reading/writing from/to the testValues array is theoretically a racecondition but if you are making sure that you are only reading and not writing at the same time or only write to different parts of the array it should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared inside the `parallel_for` loop follow the standard C++ scoping rules, hence they are local to each thread executing that portion of code.

You only have to worry about variables declared outside, which may create data races if accessed in an unsafe manner.

Answer (score 1):

This is nothing more nor less than a C++11 lambda expression. The use of `parallel_for` doesn't make it special in any way. So it follows all the rules that such an expression follows.

Personally, I wouldn't use `&` as the capture expression because it is too loose, especially for something like this where you need to carefully control which variables are used inside the lambda expression.

But yes, all variables declared inside the lambda will be stack variables that are thread-local. This includes the parameter list of the lambda function, but does not include the capture expression, even if you use a 'by value' capture.

Variables captured by value are const by default, so they should be treated as read-only copies and generally be safe. If the lambda function is declared as mutable, then I'm not sure exactly how the rules work.